# How can I change LogicApp status code to succeeded

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Within LogicApp I have a parallel branch with `run afer` set to `when fail`. If the previous step fails, appropriate actions are taken to mitigate the situation and no more action is needed, nor information on the fail. From business and user perspective that is success, so final `Status` for the whole LogicApp run shall be `Succeeded` instead of `Failed`.

How can I change the LogicApp status to `Succeeded`?
Or revoke a fail status for particular action (so assume this will solve the problem as well), when I know that it has been mitigated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the logic apps the engine determines the entire run's status by evaluating all the branch statuses. If any branch ends in failure, the entire logic app run is marked Failed.

The simplest way is add an action after the parallel like the below to add action run after both is successful and is skipped. Cause you already set the parallel action to handle the error and only one branch could be skipped, and with this setting even one branch gets exception failed the logic app still could return fail.

[image]

The last action could be any in my test I use a response action, make sure this action will success. And the below is my test, one only one action fail but only one branch is skipped one with one branch failed.

[image]

[image]

**Update with terminate**: Check my setting for terminate.

[image: supp]

[image]

Comment: Understand the idea. However there is no Response in my case. What action could I use to guarantee succeeded? Terminate with status succeeded? And what is also very important, if any other action fails except the one before two parallel branches, for e.g. any action within these two branches or anywhere else, I would like to have whole run failed.

Comment: Terminate will not work, as mentioned code is located within "for each" action.

Comment: You could just add an action like init variable. You could check my second test, in the branch if there is failure(parse json2 fails), the whole flow will fail. And if there is a exception before the branch it will fail too.   Check my update, suppose terminate could work what's your settings?

Comment: I will have to use init valuable, as Terminate is not allowed within For Each

Comment: Suppose init variable is not allowed in for each, you could set variable in for each. And maybe you could paste a detailed picture about your flow.

Comment: Works. I have used "Current time" action for the last action, as it is just one more action, variable needs two.